# untar/decompress to a stream in node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, tar

I am trying to write an AWS Lambda that will take a `tar.gz` from a `S3` bucket, inflate it and then unpack it whilst streaming the files back to another `S3` bucket.

I have this code:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var uuid = require('uuid/v4');
var tar = require('tar-stream')
var pack = tar.pack()
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  var file = 'S3://' + bucket + '/' + key;

  console.log(bucket)
  console.log(key)

  var readParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key
  };

  var dataStream = s3.getObject(readParams).createReadStream();

  var extract = tar.extract()

  extract.on('entry', function(header, stream, next) {
    console.log(header.name)
    var writeParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.JOB_PROCESSING_BUCKET,
      Key: uuid() + '-' + header.name,
      Body: stream
    };

    s3.upload(writeParams).
    on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
      console.log('Progress:', evt.loaded, '/', evt.total);
    }).
    send(function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log("An error occurred", err);
      console.log("Uploaded the file at", data.Location);
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
      next() // ready for next entry
    })
    stream.resume() // just auto drain the stream
  })

  extract.on('finish', function() {
    // all entries read
  })

  dataStream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(extract);

  callback(null, 'Gunzip Lambda Function');
};
```

It pulls the file, sorts the gzipping out and then i can see each file being extracted on entry. The code then tries to steam the file to `S3` which creates a 0kb file hangs around like its reading the stream then continues onto the next.

Why cant it seem to read/processes the stream body?
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's the best solution but the following code works for me.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const tar = require('tar-stream');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const stream = require('stream');
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.get = (event, context) => {

  var params = {
      Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
      Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
  };

  var dataStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

  var extract = tar.extract();

  extract.on('entry', function(header, inputStream, next) {

      inputStream.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3,header));

      inputStream.on('end', function() {
          next(); // ready for next entry
      });

      inputStream.resume(); // just auto drain the stream
  });

  extract.on('finish', function() {
      // all entries read
  });

  dataStream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(extract);

}

function uploadFromStream(s3,header) {
    var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

    var writeParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.JOB_PROCESSING_BUCKET,
        Key: uuid.v1() + '-' + header.name,
        Body: pass
    };

    s3.upload(writeParams, function(err, data) {
        context.done(err, data);
    });

    return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried for a couple of hours to get this to work, turns out the 'finish' event has been replaced with 'end'. So - answer above works great, just small change -

```
inputStream.on('end', function() {
  next(); // ready for next entry
});

- Should be - 

inputStream.on('finish', function() {
  next(); // ready for next entry
});
```